# load data from text file using matrix separator

Tags: matlab, file-io

I am trying to read a text file which contains the data for several matrices and load them in different matrices in matlab. An example of my text file looks like this:

> 19.623 -15.67 42.995
>   17.942 -10.923 47.112
>   23.806 -14.332 49.912
>   21.582 -11.218 46.203
>   18.031 -12.567 44.381
>   15.931 -18.897 39.046
>   18.497 -17.457 44.327
>
> 17.548 -18.604 44.24
>   15.931 -18.897 39.046
>   18.43 -16.582 43.091
>   18.497 -17.457 44.327
>   16.695 -17.627 39.364
>   17.548 -18.604 44.24
>
> 20.436 -16.416 44.281
>   17.984 -16.918 44.441
>   14.703 -17.17 40.697
>   17.078 -18.111 44.22
>   16.322 -16.342 38.961
>   19.582 -18.281 39.937
>   14.941 -16.27 39.53
>   18.43 -16.582 43.091

This file represents three matrices where the first, second and third matrices dimensions are 7x3, 6x3 and 8x3 respectively. The matrices are separated using a new line.  I have tried using S = LOAD(FILENAME) command but this command creates a 21x3 matrices which is concatenation of all the rows. How can I define a matrix separator (delimiter) for my matrices so it produces different matrices based on different segment of my file? Note that the number of all columns is always 3.

Thanks a million for all your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have NaN values in your data, you can use `textscan` with a `\n` delimiter. It produces NaN values when a blank line is read. Not very elegant but it does the trick. I am sure there are plenty of other ways of doing this.

```
fid=fopen('data','r');
data=textscan(fid,'%f','delimiter','\n');
fclose(fid);
data=cell2mat(data);
index=find(isnan(data));
A=data(1:index(1)-1);
B=data(index(1)+1:index(2)-1);
C=data(index(2)+1:end);
A=reshape(A,[3 length(A)/3])';
B=reshape(B,[3 length(B)/3])';
C=reshape(C,[3 length(C)/3])';
```

I must add that if you have any control over how these data files are created you should probably think of changing their format to either one matrix per file or a Matlab mat file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was thinking of the option creating several files but since I am using these matrices in a loop for an optimization algorithm I thought that creating several files and reading them can increase the runtime. but, I have to look at Matlab mat file. thanks again.